# How do i get the onloaded fragment?

Tags: android, fragment, onbackpressed

I wanted to know how I can get the Fragment which is onloaded on my Acticvity.
The background behind this is, that I want to change the onBackPressed method that it's switching to the right fragments. At the moment when I press "Back" the app closes, because I work alot with fragments.

Answer (score 1):

Use [addToBackStack](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)) on your fragment transaction. This way when you press the back key the transaction gets rolled back and thus your fragment disappears.

Comment: I dont get exactly what you mean, this is my code:TrainingMenuFragment trainingMenuFragment = new TrainingMenuFragment();
                FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.trainingPlanLayout, trainingMenuFragment, trainingMenuFragment.getTag()).commit();

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for the problem:

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
                FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.Layout,Fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("flow1");
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
```